# Rails - How do I access a class in the parent model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm creating a user using omniauth gem (which is working), but after the `user` is created, I'd like to create a record in the `profile` table too (but only when a `user` is created).

I decided to use a callback in the `user` model to do this.

However, after the callback is performed and it hits my `create_profile` method, I run into an error regarding a method in the `user` model:

```
undefined method `facebook' for #<Hash:0x007fdf16858200>
```

Even though I'm passing user: self to the profile model, I am not able to access methods on it.

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base


    has_one :profile
    has_many :pins
    has_many :replies, through: :pins


    after_create :build_profile


    def self.from_omniauth(auth)

        where(auth.slice(:provider, :provider_id)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|

            user.provider = auth.provider
            user.provider_id = auth.uid
            user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
            user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
            user.save

        end

    end


    def build_profile

        Profile.create_profile(user: self)

    end


    def facebook

        @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)

    end


end
```

**Profile.rb**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base


    belongs_to :user


    def self.create_profile(user)

                # undefined method `facebook' for #<Hash:0x007fdf16858200> for this line.
        user.facebook.inspect

    end

end
```

I'm new to Ruby and Rails...so, please bear with me!

I appreciate you looking this over and telling me where I'm going wrong.

Thanks,
Michael.

PS - It seems `user.inspect` returns the result of a user in my `profile.rb` model...but I am trying to access the method on that user class.

Comment: I did show the line, it's the one that reads: 'user.facebook.inspect'. It throws the error that 'facebook' is an undefined method.

Comment: Ah yes I see that. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your build profile method should pass in `self` instead if the hash `user: self`

```
def build_profile
  Profile.create_profile(self)
end
```

also, `build_<has_one_association>` is provided by rails.

you can just do

```
user.build_profile #this will return a profile object with user_id set
```

If you want to build the associated object, instead of doing

```
profile = Profile.new(:user_id => user.id)
```

You could do

```
profile = user.build_profile
```

The above will automatically initialize the profile object and set the `user_id`.
In your case, you are overriding the `build_profile` method provided by rails

Comment: You are correct with 'self' rather than passing in a hash of user: self. It works now as expected! Thanks. Could you clarify further on your second recommendation though? I'd like to know more about that.

Comment: Could anyone explain to me more about how to use this build_<has_one_association> idea?

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo: I hope my edit makes it clear. But there are lot of information about this on the internet